# tool for analyzing apache logs

Tags: untagged

we are having issues with high connection and first byte times from our apache web server.  I need a tool to go through and analyze the logs and tell me whether we were receiving high traffic at the time, patterns around the time of slowness, etc.

I am familiar with awstats but wanted to know if there are any other newer tools out there for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

few of very popular tools:

- [AWStats - Free log file analyzer for advanced statistics (GNU GPL).](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [Home of The Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)

as far as I know the best/newest tool is [Google Analytics Official Website - Web Analytics & Reporting – Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), but it doesnt really do anything with logs it works through JavaScript (so this may not work for you)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have a Hadoop/Hive deployment -

For all the time I just load apache logs to hive and run HQL for analysis, that gives me far more flexibility than any other existing tools as I can do almost all I want by just issue a SQL-like command.

Check https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted.html#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData, it's a good start point.

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Logs Viewer**

http://www.apacheviewer.com/

> Apache Logs Viewer (ALV) is a free and powerful tool which lets you
>   **monitor**, **view** and **analyze** Apache/IIS logs with more ease. It offers **search** and **filter** functionality for the log file,
>   highlighting the various http requests based on their status code.
>   There is also a report facility, thus you can generate a pie/bar chart
>   in seconds. Together with this there are also statistics where you can
>   get the top hits, top err - ors, number of status codes, total
>   bandwidth and more.
>
> Apache Logs Viewer is a great tool to use for web analytics. Use it to
>   get your website more productive, detect any errors and fix them. You
>   can determine the visitors originating country and if the referrer
>   logging is enabled than it is easier to see from which website the
>   clients are coming from, the search terms used and which pages where
>   visited.
>
> **Features**
>
> - List item
> - Easy installation (Windows Application)
> - Does not require installing on Apache Server/IIS
> - Color code Log lines according to status codes
> - Translate IP to Country using GeoLite Database (fast with no lookups)
> - Search for IP Address, Request String, Date, Referrer
> - Filter according to HTTP Status Code (or Range)
> - Export to text file/comma separated value, txt/csv
> - Visual Reports (Pie/Bar Charts)
> - Statistics

**ApacheTop**

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/

> A very simple command line utility that you can use to monitor traffic
>   real-time. It accomplishes this by parsing the apache logfiles and
>   displaying meaningful output to the screen.

**Scratch**

If you're looking for something way more basic, you can try http://scratchy.sourceforge.net/about.html.

Comment: Sometimes its hassle to download big Apache access logs and then run process and keep your workstation busy just for processing the logs.

Comment: Fair enough, here is another tool. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/

Comment: apache logs viewer's free version is totally useless. user must pay 10 euros donation to use the program. nearly all of the reports are disabled in free version.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/view/log-management/SP-CAAAC6F). It is an enterprise class solution to analyse multiple type of logs from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are many more toy's in the play box e.g. [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) or [Cacti ApacheStats](http://www.cacti.net/index.php)