# Apache log general analyzer with vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, awstats, stats

I'm using Apache in Ubuntu with several vhosts created, all pointing to the same access log. I'm already login the virtual host domain.

I'm looking for a way to have statistics reports that shows information of all vhosts in the same report, something like:

> **vhosts  ------ visits**
>
> domain1.net ---       3
>
> domain2.net ---       8

I already check tools like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/), [goaccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/) and others, but I only can get from them separated reports per vhost or only one report including all vhosts as if they were only one.

I checked another answers like [tool for analyzing apache logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/455809/tool-for-analyzing-apache-logs), [A software to analyze Apache log is needed](https://serverfault.com/questions/375794/a-software-to-analyze-apache-log-is-needed) and https://serverfault.com/questions/296316/web-log-analyzer-that-can-generate-a-single-report-for-multiple-domains but doesn't solve my needs either.

Take in consideration that I doesn't want reports like I get from [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) (after some configuration) for all my vhosts resources, I want to check the differences between vhosts.

My log format is (can be changed if needed):

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

And the log looks like:

> test.leticia.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2013:12:23:25 -0300] "GET
> /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 301 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93
> Safari/537.36"
>
> test.leticia.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2013:12:26:30
> -0300] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 301 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93
> Safari/537.36"

Just let me know if another information is required. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For archive purpose:

I found that webalizer has a section where I can check the Hits, Files, KBytes and Visits of the list of vhosts in my Apache. The section is "[Sites]"

Just be sure of use a LogFormat that includes the vhost, for example:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %O "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"" vhost_combined
```

The log appears as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple shell script to count the number of occurrences of each virtual host:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr
```

Comment: Thanks, all seems that I should use shell scripts as you mention, or a tool like awstats or webalizer with information per vhost. I can't find a tool that show reports centralizing all vhosts.